# Why does ScrollView/Webview object in xcode include some kind of margin?

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview

I'm really getting extremely mad with Xcode, trying to get a ScrollView correctly working. I'm having in fact 2 problems, but I'll separate it in two questions.

First of all, check out this screenshot.
[image: Screenshot of Xcode, top of simulator]

Whether I drag the `ScrollView` to the top of `view` or just to the bottom border of the navigation bar, the web view (white square) stays about 60px from the nav bar, as you can see in the simulator.

The only way for me to have the web view aligned just below the nav bar is by dragging the `Scrollview` to the top of the view, at the top of the nav bar, and dragging the web view all the way to the top too.. Which places (in Storyboard) the web view behind the nav bar. Seems a bit odd, isn't it? The web view object has no attributes assigned to it which could have created that strange space.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

*Note: I have less than 40 hours of Xcode experience resulting in knowing nothing of Objective-C lines, but the Xcode interface itself. Learning by tutorials and practice*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view controller add this method...

```
- (BOOL) automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets
{
    return NO;
}
```

This will fix it for you.

Comment: I tried googling for answers, related to where I should write your strings, without luck. I've pasted it in the mainviewcontroller.m file, but I see no difference. Pasting it in other files, such as mainviewcontroller.h file or any other file/part of file fails to load the simulator. Could you extend your answer where to write your code? Thanks

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer you are adding your WebView to a view that belongs to a view controller. That view controller will (should) be a subclass of `UIViewController` maybe `MyWebViewController` or something like that. You should put this method into that sub class. So `MyWebViewController.m`.